# Can we use QT to develop cross-platform application works among Mac/Win/Linux/iOS/Android

Tags: cross-platform

I just want to know if there is a way to develop an application that will work on all the popular platforms? Does QT can do that? or other kind of languages. I don't need the web application, i need the native application. Desktop application on the computer and mobile application on the mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

[Xojo](http://www.xojo.com) can create Mac/Win/Linux and iOS native apps. It cannot do native Android apps, but its web apps do run on Android.

Answer (score 0):

QT can definitely do that, though understand is a c++ framework(term used loosely, is way more than that), so it follows c++ principles, write-once-compile-everywhere, which implies you need, for certain devices to actually have the device(or a virtual copy), eg: for android you get the sdk and the virtual device can play your app(in any OS), for an Apple and IOS you need a mac to install XCode and the virtual device or physical device.

The main language is c++, so knowledge of it is necessary, though they also implement QML for creating fancy and advance UI design that are independent to the OS, is based on JS and is really fast to get something nice and animated to the screen.

There is also a Python version of it, again QT is a very flexible and varying tool, the only small point of concern for me is the style they choose for their IDE, not all the views are dock-able and no tabs for multiple file view, on the other side their intellisense/code helper and debugger, are far better than any other IDE(Yes I'm talking about you VS)